# How to disable fast boot in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bios

I have a Dell Optiplex 7060 computer I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in the beginning (I upgraded with all new versions of Ubuntu) now Ubuntu 20.04 is installed. The only problem with this setup is not going to the BIOS screen I try every key on the keyboard still not working. After some research, I find out maybe fast boot is enabled. And I try to do disabled it. I read some articles, they suggest changing `GRUB_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub` it maybe help. Depend on those articles I changed `GRUB_DEFAULT` to `2` after that nothing working it is just a black screen.

What I want now, is to find a way to format my computer or at least return back to the installed version.

Please help I don't know what do to.

Comment: You will need to boot with a Live USB/DVD and repair your Grub file from there.

Comment: How can I do that? can you give me a guideline? the main problem, I can't go to the bios. I want to format my computer and I don't want this setup anymore.

Comment: [This documentation from Canonical](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) gives you a step-by-step to create a Live USB (if you need one), mount your partitions, and gain access to the grub file. Hopefully it will give you what you need to fix your computer, too 